# Flipping textviews issue

Tags: android, view, flip

suppose i have 3 textviews set in horizontal LinearLayout which is in one screen.I know i can flip textviews with help of ViewFlipper.But is there anyway to flip portion means  if i will flip then one textview will be gone and two textviews will remain.

Just see this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Pbo-d62ivY&feature=player_embedded&noredirect=1).

Comment: are you asking about Animation in ViewFlipper ?

Answer (score 0):

See this for ViewFlipper animation

http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-view-flipper-in-android.html

or you can use HorozontalPager also
link https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager

Comment: can you help me? see the link i have provided in my question. that's a video link.Go to 0:40 seconds and see.How screens are flipping and headings are flipping.Screens are flipping in different motions than headings.Any idea how they are doing ? I did the screens but what about headings ?

Comment: The heading is noting but Galley. You have to use HorozontalPager with Galley on top.

Comment: ok thanks first of all.I am using viewpager only but how to use gallery on top little more idea plz.And how it is moving slower that screens.